# checkboxInput and conditionalPanel in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

When choose s1, only show one sidebarPanel and mainPanel,the results alpha was 0.05 and power was 0.8. When choose s2, only show one sidebarPanel and mainPanel,the results alpha was 0.1 and power was 0.9.

This is my ui.R and server.R.

Below is the code for my ui.R file:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
  tabsetPanel(
    navbarMenu("Means",
           tabPanel("One Mean"),
           tabPanel("Two Means",
                    wellPanel(
                      checkboxInput(inputId = "s1", label = "S1", value = FALSE),
                      checkboxInput(inputId = "s2", label = "S2", value = FALSE)
                    ),
                    conditionalPanel(condition="input.s1==true",
                      sidebarPanel(
                        p(strong("Error Rates")),
                        numericInput("alpha", label="Alpha", min=0, max=1,value=0.05),
                        numericInput("power", "Power", 0.8),
                        actionButton("submit","Submit")
                      ),
                      mainPanel(
                        tabsetPanel(
                          tabPanel("Main",
                                   tableOutput("Table"),
                                   uiOutput("Text")
                          )
                        )
                      )
                    ),
                    conditionalPanel(condition="input.s2==true",
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       p(strong("Error Rates")),
                                       numericInput("alpha", label="Alpha", min=0, max=1,value=0.1),
                                       numericInput("power", "Power", 0.9),
                                       actionButton("submit","Submit")
                                     ),
                                     mainPanel(
                                       tabsetPanel(
                                         tabPanel("Main",
                                                  tableOutput("Table"),
                                                  textOutput("Text")
                                         )
                                       )
                                     )
                    )
          )
    ))))
```

Below is the code for my server.R file:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
output$Table <- renderTable({
if(input$submit > 0) { 
  output<-data.frame(input$alpha,input$power)
  output
}
})

output$Text<-renderText({
if(input$submit > 0) {
  paste("alpha and power are",input$alpha,"and",input$power)
}
})
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your welcome. I don't see a question here. Can you be a bit more explicit as to what you want?

Comment: If I choose s1, then only show alpha=0.05 Panel,  If I choose s1, then only show alpha=0.1 Panel. Now two Panel in one page. Thank you.

Comment: @stata Would you need both `s1` and `s2` to be selected at any time? How do you expect it to work in that case?

Comment: @krish no,only choose one.

Comment: @stata: Ok, then in that case it makes sense to use a `radiobutton`. Not a solution but just better practice.

Comment: Why don't you add the question to your post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you. You would need to slightly modify the server code to handle the different IDs. You cannot have the same id for the various UI elements.

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
  tabsetPanel(
    navbarMenu("Means",
               tabPanel("One Mean"),
               tabPanel("Two Means",
                        wellPanel(
                          radioButtons(inputId = "buttons", "Selections", c("S1", "S2"), selected = "S1", inline = TRUE)
                        ),
                        sidebarPanel(
                          conditionalPanel(condition = "input.buttons == 'S1'",
                                           p(strong("Error Rates")),
                                           numericInput("alpha", label="Alpha", min=0, max=1,value=0.05),
                                           numericInput("power", "Power", 0.8),
                                           actionButton("submit","Submit")
                                           ),
                          conditionalPanel(condition = "input.buttons == 'S2'",
                                           p(strong("Error Rates")),
                                           numericInput("alpha1", label="Alpha", min=0, max=1,value=0.1),
                                           numericInput("power1", "Power", 0.9),
                                           actionButton("submit1","Submit")
                                           )
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(
                            tabPanel("Main",
                                     tableOutput("Table"),
                                     textOutput("Text")
                            )
                          )
                        )
               )
    ))))
```

Comment: Thank you. Now Submit with s1 is action,but Submit with s2 is not action.

Comment: @stata, I didn't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: When I choose s2 and submit, The contents of Main was blank.

Comment: @stata, like I mentioned in the answer, you will need to modify the server code to handle the different IDs for the UI elements. You cannot have the same IDs for elements, so I have changed the IDs (`alpha` and `alpha1` and so on)...

Comment: @ krish, Thank you. If I want to use  same IDs in ui, how to modify it?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question recently while researching a similar [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208012/how-to-add-a-conditional-selectinput-based-on-a-selected-checkboxinput-in-shin).

This is not an alternative to the above answer but I thought it necessary to point out as the title of the question is ***checkboxInput and conditionalPanel in shiny***.

The simple answer to the the checkboxInput condition at least is as below:

`conditionalPanel(condition="input.s1==1",`

and

`conditionalPanel(condition="input.s2==1",`

Obviously there is still the issue of unique IDs and the fact that `radioButtons()` is more appropriate in this context which are dealt with above.